# How can I eliminate InverseLaplaceTransform returning complex

Tags: differential-equations, complex, integral-transforms

I tried this:

```
F = InverseLaplaceTransform[
  1/((1 + s^2) (1 + (s + 1/2)^2)) + 
   Exp[-Pi*s]*1/((1 + s^2) (1 + (s + 1/2)^2)), s, t]
```

But it returns an answer with a lot of complex numbers. Is there a way that I can get a strictly real answer?

Using Mathematica 11.2.0

Thanks.

Comment: `\\ComplexExpand\\FullSimplify` yields `4/17 ((4 Cos[t] - Sin[t]) (-1 + UnitStep[-\[Pi] + t]) - E^(-t/2) (4 Cos[t] + Sin[t]) (-1 + E^(\[Pi]/2) UnitStep[-\[Pi] + t]))`, which should be good enough.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Nice! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> `\\ComplexExpand\\FullSimplify` yields `4/17 ((4 Cos[t] - Sin[t]) (-1 + UnitStep[-\[Pi] + t]) - E^(-t/2) (4 Cos[t] + Sin[t]) (-1 + E^(\[Pi]/2) UnitStep[-\[Pi] + t]))`, which should be good enough. –
> AccidentalFourierTransform
> [Apr 8, 2018 at 1:11](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170643/how-can-i-eliminate-inverselaplacetransform-returning-complex#comment448562_170643)

BTW, I think the `\\` is a typo. Try `F // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify`.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use an exact number or parameters when you are using InverseLaplaceTransform, for instance, in your expression use an instead of 1/2, and after taking the inverse substitute it again.

```
F = InverseLaplaceTransform[1/((1 + s^2) (1 + (s + a)^2)) + Exp[-Pi*s]*1/((1 + s^2) (1 + (s + a)^2)), s, t] /. {a -> 1/2}
```

Comment: `1/2` is an exact number..

Comment: This is equivalent to the OP's: `InverseLaplaceTransform[(4 + 4 E^(-\[Pi] s))/(
 5 + 4 s + 9 s^2 + 4 s^3 + 4 s^4), s, t]`. However the `a` trick doesn't work if I replace `4`: `InverseLaplaceTransform[(a + a E^(-\[Pi] s))/(5 + a s + 9 s^2 + a s^3 + a s^4), s, t] /. a -> 4` still gives an answer with `I`. Do I have to keep guessing where to substitute the parameter until I happen to succeed, or is there a general theory that tells us how to use `a`?